# gbm confidence intervals in R?

Tags: r, predict, confidence-interval, gbm

Anybody know how to calculate confidence intervals from the gbm.predict() function? I'd like a method to ascertain a 95% confidence band on my gbm predictions.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean predict.gbm from the gbm package?

Comment: The confidence should be calculated based on your source data and the fitted model.  Any predictions you make can be no better than that calculation.